# In python, how do I serialize objects containing function objects and back?

Tags: python, function, object, serialization

Let's say that I have a dictionary containing a reference to a function and some other elements, like:

```
mydict={'a':1.0,'b':7.89,'c':<function mylib.sum>}
```

is there any way to serialize this, ie transforming into a string that can be saved somewhere and then transformed back into a dictionary, correctly including the function reference?

I tried with cPickle, but it explictly would not allow function objects. It kind of works if I do

```
eval(str(mydict).replace('<function mylib.sum>','mylib.sum'))
```

but I am not sure how to generalize that.

Thanks

Comment: Functions defined at the top level of a module can be pickled (by named reference). http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled